# Incoherent XPath output

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I just discovered XPath and I'm trying to use it in order to parse an XML file. I read a few courses about it, but I am stuck with a problem. When I try to get a NodeList from the file, the getLength() method always returns 0.
However, when I try a

```
document.getElementsByTagName("crtx:env").getLength()
```

The output is correct (7 in my case).
I do not really understand, because my nodelist is built according to my Document, the output should be similar, isn't it ?

Here is a part of my code :

```
    IFile                   f               = (IFile) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
    String                  fileURL         = f.getLocation().toOSString();
    DocumentBuilderFactory  builderFactory  = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder         builder         = null;

    try {
        builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Document document = null;

    if (builder != null){
        try{
            document = builder.parse(fileURL);
            System.out.println("DOCUMENT URI : " + document.getDocumentURI());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("builder null");
    }


    XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    NodeList nodeList = null;

    try {
        nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("crtx:env").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("NODELIST SIZE : " + nodeList.getLength());
    System.out.println(document.getElementsByTagName("crtx:env").getLength());

}
```

The first System.out.println() returns coherent output (a good URI), but the two last lines return a different number.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is defined for XML with namespaces so set

```
DocumentBuilderFactory  builderFactory  = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Then to use a path with a namespace prefix you need to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext%28javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext%29 to bind the prefix(es) used to namespace URIs, see https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xpath_apis.html#namespacecontext for an example

With a namespace aware DOM you will need to change your getElementsByTagName call to use getElementsByTagNameNS however.